# Can we structure the Javascript object like this using reduce or something else?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, object, reduce

I have object something like below which I am getting from API;

```
const people = [
                  { name: 'Alex joe', age: 28 ,date:'2022-08-22'},
                  { name: 'Alice', age: 21 ,date:'2022-08-18'},
                  { name: 'Anki', age: 25 ,date:'2022-08-22'},
                  { name: 'Max', age: 20 ,date:'2022-08-18'},
                  { name: 'Jane', age: 20 ,date:'2022-08-20'},
                  { name: 'John schinger', age: 17 ,date:'2022-08-22'},
                  { name: 'Alice', age: 21 ,date:'2022-08-20'},
                  { name: 'Max', age: 20 ,date:'2022-08-20'},
                  { name: 'Jane', age: 20 ,date:'2022-08-22'},
               ];
```

I want it to be sorted wrt date mentioned in the each object like below, so that I can use it in SectionList of React.

```
const output = [
  {title:'2022-08-18', data:[
                              { name: 'Alice', age: 21 ,date:'2022-08-18'},
                              { name: 'Max', age: 20 ,date:'2022-08-18'}
                            ]
  },
  {title:'2022-08-20', data:[
                              { name: 'Jane', age: 20 ,date:'2022-08-20'},
                              { name: 'Alice', age: 21 ,date:'2022-08-20'},
                              { name: 'Max', age: 20 ,date:'2022-08-20'}        
                            ]
  },
  {title:'2022-08-22', data:[
                                { name: 'Jane', age: 20 ,date:'2022-08-22'},
                                { name: 'Anki', age: 25 ,date:'2022-08-22'},
                                { name: 'Alex joe', age: 28 ,date:'2022-08-22'},
                                { name: 'John schinger', age: 17 ,date:'2022-08-22'},        
                            ]
  }
  ]
```

I want to use this data in my sectionList which asks for title and data as key, tried to use reduce but failed to get the result...
can please someone help me out with it, Thanks..

Comment: Can you show us how you did your `reduce`?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/328193)  You are encouraged to make an attempt.  If during your attempt you encounter a specific problem, such as a specific operation producing an error or an unexpected result, we can help with that.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
people.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const existingDateIndex = acc.findIndex(
    (element) => element.title === item.date
  );

  if (existingDateIndex > -1) {
    acc[existingDateIndex].data.push(item);
  } else {
    acc.push({ title: item.date, data: [item] });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```